# Can Kuranishi families glue together to give a moduli space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, coherent-sheaves

In his article "Moduli spaces of vector bundles on K3 surfaces and symplectic manifolds", Mukai constructs moduli of simple sheaves on a K3 surface through a theorem that asserts the existence of a Kuranishi family, simply saying that this IS the moduli space. I would like to make this construction more precise in this way. Starting with the Quot scheme $Quot(X,N,P)$ of coherent sheaves on a surface $X$ with given Hilbert polinomial and quozient of the $\mathcal{O}_X^N$ sheaf (so that a point in $Quot$ is represented by a morphism $$q:\mathcal{O}_X^N\to F.)$$
I can consider the action of $GL(N)$ on it defined by right-composition, i.e.
$$ g\cdot [q]:=[q\circ g].$$
If $F$ is a simple sheaf then the point $[q]\in Quot$ is a smooth point and its stabilizator is trivial, so Luna's Slice Theorem assures us that there exists a smooth (locally closed) subvariety $V$ (just right the slice étale) that contains $[q]$. Eventually, the universal property of the $Quot$ descends to a universal properties on $V$ and in this way $V$ is a Kuranishi family! But this, of course, cannot be the moduli space of simple sheaves, so I'm asking if the Kuranishi families constructed in this way can glue each others giving the required moduli space, or if this idea is incorrect. In this last case, I ask you if you know some other construction or some other reference in addition to the classical ones.

Thank you!

Comment: I have partially aswered the question. In fact, I can glue togheter these spaces in a unique way thanks to the universal property. Now the problem is: why is the spaces constructed in this way the moduli space of simple sheaves on a K3? Why does it represent the moduli functor?